# Application crashes on device restart

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

iPhone app that I'm working on(xcode 4.2) runs fine but it crashes(doesn't even show the launch image) if I restart the device(iPhone 4 on 5.0) and launch it again. But when I connect the device to my mac it works fine.(without even building the app again / when xcode is closed)

Where do I look for bugs? Please advice.

Comment: Thanks, the application works fine on the simulator. It even works fine when I deploy it for the first time on the device. It starts crashing only when I restart the device.

Comment: When you have your device connected to the iPhone, and start and app and it crashes, you can either get the crash report using Xcode probing the device, or it in some situations gets synced to the mac and shows up in the Console app. Look at those and see if you can see any reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally figured out the problem. The SenTesting.framework was the issue. Managed to look at the crash log & it threw the error

> Library not loaded:/Developer/Library/Frameworks/SenTestingKit.framework/SenTestingKit

Searched on stackoverflow & found this link

[Why is SenTestingKit causing my app to crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456020/why-is-sentestingkit-causing-my-app-to-crash)

Removed the reference in the Build Phases & now it works perfectly fine even after the device is restarted.